# Passing function call as a parameter to printf & Reentrancy

Tags: c, multithreading, printf, reentrancy

As per my knowledge , `printf()` is threadsafe and not reentrant.
Now if I pass the result of a function call as a parameter like this:

```
printf("\"%d\" squared is \"%d\".\n", 5, squareOfInteger(5));
```

will the function `squareofInteger` also become threadsafe in a multithreaded program?

Comment: Short answer : no, `squareOfInteger()` need to be thread safe by itself.

Comment: Why do you think so?...What kind of magic do you imagine behind printf?...

Comment: OP, can you explain what you mean by "threadsafe" and "non reentrant"? Especially how that could be changed from unsafe to safe by being called from another function. We seem to have different understandings of those terms.

Comment: @Stargateur You probably have to explain your understanding of "thread safe" to be helpful for OP. Though I am pretty sure that you and me agree much better on the term than you and OP.

Comment: You are not passing a function call. I am sure a call is not a type in C. What you are passing is the result of the call. It is the same as `int res = squareOfIntger(5);` and then passing `res`.

Comment: calling a function squareOfIntger() from a threadsafe function (printf in this case) does not mean that squareOfIntger() will be threadsafe!

Comment: @ShuvamDas: Note that `squareOfInteger()` will be called before `printf()` is called — it will be called while the arguments to `printf()` are being evaluated, but the call to `squareOfInteger()` will be complete before `printf()` is actually called.

Comment: So is the case with arguments of a function. Isn't it?I fail to see the point. Wouldn't the evaluation of args always be done in the same thread that has invoked the function in the first place? or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

No. Counterexample:

```
int squareOfInteger(int x)
{
    static int val;
    val = x*x; /* Possible race condition here */
    return val;
}
```

This function is evaluated by different threads (concurrently) before `printf` is called and the result is handed over to `printf`.